WPF Wizard: How to grey out the "Next" button when no radio button is selected yet
I want the "Next" Button of the Wizard to be only accessible once a selection has been made for the radio button.
<Window x:Class="WpfWizard.WizardWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfWizard"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="WizardWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:Wizard FinishButtonClosesWindow="True">
            <xctk:WizardPage x:Name="IntroPage" 
                             Title="Welcome to my Wizard"
                             Description="This Wizard will walk you though how to do something.">
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <RadioButton GroupName="ServerSelection" Margin="20">Old Server Environment</RadioButton>
                            <RadioButton GroupName="ServerSelection" Margin="20">New Server Environment</RadioButton>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </xctk:WizardPage>
            <xctk:WizardPage x:Name="Page1" PageType="Interior"
                             Title="Page 1"
                             Description="This is the first page in the process."
                             NextPage="{Binding ElementName=Page2}"
                             PreviousPage="{Binding ElementName=IntroPage}">
                             
            </xctk:WizardPage>
            <xctk:WizardPage x:Name="Page2" PageType="Interior"
                             Title="Page 2"
                             Description="This is the second page in the process">
            </xctk:WizardPage>

            <xctk:WizardPage x:Name="LastPage" PageType="Interior"
                             Title="Last Page"
                             Description="This is the last page in the process"
                             CanFinish="True">
            </xctk:WizardPage>
        </xctk:Wizard>
    </Grid>
</Window>

I tried implementing the solution from this question, however i cannot use the Page Attribute within the WizardPage so it does not quite work for me.
